# Desperately Seeking Search - not filter - Capability in Firebug Console

Tags: firefox, search, console, firebug

I badly need a Search feature in the Firebug Console.

There is a supposed "search" input field in the upper-right corner of the console, but it's not a search at all - it's a filter.  It omits all lines that don't match the search term.  This removes all the context log lines around the lines with the search term in it.

Does anyone know of a way to make Firebug's Console perform a real Search, just like the ordinary Search feature on Web Pages in Firefox?

Is there an add-in  that I'm not finding that can deliver this capability?

Answer (score 0):

Firebug does not have a feature like that and, as far as I know, there isn't any extension doing that.

Note that I've [requested this feature](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/3111) years ago.